# EAN13 Barcode Encoding in Haskell: How to test it?

Tags: haskell, testing, encoding, barcode, decoding

I am completing the [chapter 12 of **Real World Haskell**](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/barcode-recognition.html). In this chapter, the author explains how to perform Barcode Recognition with [EAN13 encoding](http://www.barcodeisland.com/ean13.phtml#Encoding%20Table).

I reproduced the most of the code from [the book snippets into my repo](https://github.com/mberlanda/real_world_haskell/blob/bf956f597a4efb377c174502a1d2752be184cd79/ch12/Barcode.hs) and when I finally arrived to check if my over 300 rows of code where working as expected, I got a bad news:

```
-- Finding the Correct Sequence
*Main> let input = zip (runLengths $ encodeEAN13 "9780132114677") (cycle [Zero, One])
*Main> listToMaybe . solve . candidateDigits $ input
Just [0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] -- WRONG Actual
Just [9,7,8,0,1,3,2,1,1,4,6,7,7] -- Expected
```

Since the book was published, I noticed the some type signatures have changed such as:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import qualified Data.Map as M
Prelude M> :t M.lookup
M.lookup :: Ord k => k -> M.Map k a -> Maybe a
-- in the book: M.lookup :: (Ord k, Monad m) => k -> M.Map k a -> m a
```

I tried to reproduce in GHCi every example and, except from the last one, I always get the same result as the book.

**Has anyone covered that topic from this book?**

The author is not explaining every single line of code and, in particular, the `input` variable is not defined anywhere `let input = zip (runLengths $ encodeEAN13 "9780132114677") (cycle [Zero, One])`

**Some EAN13 encoded barcode for testing?**

In case no one knows this book, would you have some sample of *EAN13 encoded* barcodes such as:

```
*Main M> encodeEAN13 "9780132114677"
"101011101100010010100111001100101000010101011011001100110110011010111001010000100010010001001010000101"
```

To make sure that my tests on functions are correct?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two bugs in your implementation:

First, in `encodeDigits`, you've written `splitAt 5` when it should be `splitAt 6`.  This fixes the encoding bug noted by @Brian Anderson.

Second, in `bestScores`, you've written:

```
[(distance d (scaleToOne ps), n) | d <- srl, n <- digits]
```

when you should have written:

```
zip [distance d (scaleToOne ps) | d <- srl] digits
```

This fixes your decoding bug.

I wish I could say I used my superhuman debugging skills to find these bugs, but I just happened to have my own copy of `Barcode.hs` around from when I did Chapter 12 myself a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It looks like there are three problems with your sequence of 1's and 0's. The first is your [A] EAN-13 center code seems to be overwriting the beginning of your sixth character. It should really be where [B] is. And you've got an extra 4 zeroes and an extra end marker tacked on to the end of your sequence.

Here's a tool that does the work of generating the checksum and laying out the 1's and 0's:

```js
var arrayCodeEANBin, arrayStructEAN;
arrayCodeEANBin = [ [ '0001101', '0011001', '0010011', '0111101', '0100011', '0110001', '0101111', '0111011', '0110111', '0001011' ], [ '0100111', '0110011', '0011011', '0100001', '0011101', '0111001', '0000101', '0010001', '0001001', '0010111' ], [ '1110010', '1100110', '1101100', '1000010', '1011100', '1001110', '1010000', '1000100', '1001000', '1110100' ] ];
arrayStructEAN = ['000000', '001011', '001101', '001110', '010011', '011001', '011100', '010101', '010110', '011010']

var strRaw = "";
var strText = "";

function funcEAN() { // EAN-13
var intSumOdd = 0, intSumEven = 0, intCheck, i, j, strStruct;
// Compute check digit and add it to raw string
 for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {
  intSumEven += parseInt(strText[i]);
  intSumOdd += parseInt(strText[i+1]);
 }
 intCheck = ((intSumOdd * 3) + intSumEven) % 10;
 if (intCheck > 0) {
  intCheck = 10 - intCheck;
 }
 strText += intCheck;
// Converts Code EAN array into string of 1's and 0's
 strRaw = "101"
// First six bar sequences
 for (i = 1; i < 7; i += 1) {
   strStruct = arrayStructEAN[strText[0]];
   strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[strStruct[i-1]][strText[i]];
 }
// Middle sequence
 strRaw += "01010";
// Last six bar sequences, including check digit
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
  strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[2][strText[i+7]];
 }
 strRaw += "101";
} // End EAN-13


var buttonBarcode = document.getElementById("btnGenBar");
buttonBarcode.onclick = function () {
 strText = document.getElementById("textBarcode").value;
 funcEAN();
 document.getElementById("textRaw").value = strRaw;
 document.getElementById("textRaw").select();
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>EAN-13 Barcodes in vanilla JavaScript</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
 <div id="inputForm">
  Enter Text:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textBarcode" tabindex=1/>
  &nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnGenBar" value="Gen 1's and 0's" tabindex=4/>
 </div>
 <p></p>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <p></p>
 <textarea rows="3" cols="110" id="textRaw" tabindex=0></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./SO_JS-EAN-13.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to see the actual barcode generated, I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/KXEWdK). It doesn't add the formatted text, but the barcode scans.